Delphi Tcxgrid GetProperties change button caption error
procedure TFrmTySipAyrinti.cxcol_eslestirme_stokidGetProperties(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  var AProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties);
 var
  StokID, i,ColIdx,RecIdx : Integer;
  AColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  var vText : String;
begin
//  inherited;
   StokID :=VarToInt(DBGCxFaturaReader.DataController.Values[ARecord.RecordIndex, cxcol_stokid.Index]);
    // AProperties kontrolü
    if (AProperties = nil) or not (AProperties is TcxButtonEditProperties) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;
    // Buttons listesinin kontrolü
    if TcxButtonEditProperties(AProperties).Buttons.Count = 0 then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

//
//  if StokID <>0 then begin
  AProperties.Buttons.Items[0].Caption :='OK';   
//  end else begin
//  AProperties.Buttons.Items[0].Caption :='NULL';   
//  end;

I am using Delphi. When I use the code like this it works fine. However when I use it like below it gives an error. Access violation at address ....
AProperties.Buttons.Items[0].Caption :='OK'; the only thing that changes
procedure TFrmTySipAyrinti.cxcol_eslestirme_stokidGetProperties(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableItem; ARecord: TcxCustomGridRecord;
  var AProperties: TcxCustomEditProperties);
 var
  StokID, i,ColIdx,RecIdx : Integer;
  AColumn: TcxCustomGridTableItem;
  var vText : String;
begin
//  inherited;
   StokID :=VarToInt(DBGCxFaturaReader.DataController.Values[ARecord.RecordIndex, cxcol_stokid.Index]);
    // AProperties kontrolü
    if (AProperties = nil) or not (AProperties is TcxButtonEditProperties) then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;
    // Buttons listesinin kontrolü
    if TcxButtonEditProperties(AProperties).Buttons.Count = 0 then
    begin
      Exit;
    end;

//
  if StokID <>0 then begin
  AProperties.Buttons.Items[0].Caption :='OK';   
  end else begin
  AProperties.Buttons.Items[0].Caption :='NULL';   
  end;

I tried many things but couldn't find a solution. My goal is to change the caption of the Button in Cxgrid.

See the OnGetProperties manual, specifically the Important Limitations and the TIP below it.
